Running harmonic regression on time series
I am trying to run a harmonic regression on a quarterly series.
The software gets confused by the frequency of the time series when I try to do the above.
For example, I wish to know if there is a cycle of length 6 quarters:
> plot(fourier(ts(1:100,frequency=4),K=6))

Error in ...fourier(x, K, 1:NROW(x)) : 
  K must be not be greater than period/2

I have to trick the software and  do :
> fourier(ts(1:100,frequency=100),K=6)[1:3,]

it works.
How do I tell the software that I am looking for a cycle of length 6 or more quarters?
Edit: The parameter K controls how fast the sinosoids are oscillating.
K = j does j/N cycles per sample or j cycles in N samples.
We have N=100 samples in this case.
Cycle of length 6 means will do N/6 cycles in N points.
100/6 = 16.6 ie. j = 16.6 or around 16.
Hence I think now, for a cycle of length 6 I have to do :
fourier(ts(1:100,frequency=100),K=16)[1:3,]
Using K=6 was a mistake.
However, my original query is still in my mind.
Can I not tell the software that I need K= 16 in a quarterly series with 100 points ?
Since I have a 100 points I surely can estimate a cycle of length 6. I Should not have to trick the software by putting frequency=100.

Did you mean frequency=4 for quarterly data ? I think we can have cycles of any length in any series. Example: I can have a business cycle of length 6-32 quarters in a quarterly time series. The Nyquist rate of 1/2 the sampling frequency does not prevent detection of long cycles (only of the short).

I was answering a comment which has been deleted.

The forecast::fourier() function uses the frequency of the ts dataset to specify the periodicity of the fourier terms. For a periodicity of 6 quarters (assuming quarterly data) you would need to use a frequency of 6 for your data (at least for the fourier terms).
library(forecast)
#> Registered S3 method overwritten by 'quantmod':
#>   method            from
#>   as.zoo.data.frame zoo
# Create fourier terms with periodicity 6 and K=3 harmonics
x <- fourier(ts(1:100,frequency=6),K=3)

# Plot the terms as quarterly data (frequency = 4) starting in 1980
plot(ts(x, start = 1980, frequency = 4))


Created on 2024-08-07 with reprex v2.1.0
Note that K is not the periodicity of the fourier terms, but instead the number of harmonics. Also note that fourier terms are appropriate for seasonal patterns and cannot fully capture the behaviour of cyclical patterns.

Many thanks for your reply. Yes I am trying to model cyclical behavior in a time series. Query 1: Does it matter if I do frequency =6 or frequency = 100  in the underlying time series to model 3 harmonics? I do not think so. Query 2 : What would be a better way to model cyclical behavior?

I suggest you learn more about fourier terms. Cyclical patterns can be modeled using ARIMA-type models. https://otexts.com/fpp3/dhr.html
